# Angular Bootstrap Window Modal Opener Route Changes

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

Following this plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/33572YOSA2s89uEiLmKB?p=preview
I've managed to load into bootstrap modal partial content based on route:

Route defined as follows:

```
.when('/profile', {
                                   templateUrl: 'modalContainer',
                               })
```

Controller hooked up:

```
myApp.controller('DashboardModal', function($scope, $modal) {
  $modal.open({
    templateUrl : 'Partials/Dashboard.html',
    controller: 'DashboardController',

  });
});
```

Finally in html:

```
 <div>
      <a href="#/profile">Click here to open modal!</a>
    </div>

    <script type="text/ng-template" id="modalContainer">
        <div ng-controller="DashboardModal"></div>
    </script>
```

My Problem is that the route of the opener window changes when modal opens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code is working exactly as designed. What the `<a href="#/profile">` tag is doing is making a call to the `$routeProvider` with the path '/profile'. Looking in the script.js, you can see this is a new view which is set up to look like a modal in the HTML. You are navigating to a new view, not opening a modal.